# ERROR: resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 16

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

can anyone help me in solving this issue
I try to learn android development but whenever I run my hello world apllication in android studio using emulator,it will show the error

> Cannot launch AVD in emulator. Output: emulator: WARNING: userdata
>   partition is resized from 550 M to 800 M ERROR: resizing partition
>   e2fsck failed with exit code 16 Warning: requested ram_size 1536M too
>   big, reduced to 1024M Hax is enabled Hax ram_size 0x40000000 HAX is
>   working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.

I tried to solve it on my own but I failed